# What's with the dependency of x on y?

Tags: calculus

[image]

In the above figure, why are x and y considered to be independent variables?

Answer (score 1):

There is actually no reason obtained strictly from reading the particular question *on its own* to indicate that they should be so.

It is just that in formulating batch of questions *of these forms*, variables $x, y$ are typically taken to be independent, and words to that effect *should* have been stated earlier in the problem set.   However the authors might just have been lazy and forgot to do so.